# Unable to charge HP Envy Intel i7 11th gen with Comsol 25600 power brick

Tags: usb, laptop, power-supply, battery, power

I purchased and HP laptop as above. The battery won't get through a full day on a charge, so I purchased a Comsol power bank. I have contacted Comsol and have been told that it should charge a laptop through USB-C, and HP have indicated that I should be able to charge my laptop over USB. The power bank can provide 100W of power.  I am using the USB-C cable provided by Comsol, but I can't charge my laptop with my powerbank.

Does anyone have any suggestions how I can charge my laptop with the power bank?

Comment: Have you asked the manufacturer for support and for possibly returning the unit for another one?

Comment: I disabled USB charging in the BIOS. It seems to work intermittently now. It seems to only work when the cable is used the right way round. Is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: I am not sure if USB cables are uni-directional.